# Tkinter '.after()' help, GUI window doesn't open

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

I'm trying to make an program for twitch, where the twitch chat can vote by typing a command ("!voteA") for example, and the chatbot-code will count the votes, and show them in a GUI window, I've already gotten pretty far, but my GUI window is not opening and I think it has something to do with the self.after(10, self.get_votes) line, could anyone help me out?

Here's the code: (it has some more tabs like Read, Socket, Initialize, Settings, but I don't think they're relevant for now, if they are I can also post them)

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Read import getUser, getMessage
from Socket import openSocket, sendMessage
from Initialize import joinRoom
from collections import OrderedDict

class App(tk.Frame): #Toplevel is a frame with a specific use. Unless there is another window, you want a Frame.
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            "voteA",
            "voteB",
            "voteC"]

        self.s = openSocket()
        joinRoom(self.s)
        self.readbuffer = ""

        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self['background']='black'
        self.pack()
        self.master.geometry("+200+200")
        # self.master.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)

        self.labels = OrderedDict()
        for option in options:
            label = tk.Label(
                self,
                bg="black",
                fg="white",
                font="HouseSlant-Regular 30",
                anchor="w")
            label.pack()
            self.labels[option] = [0, label]

        self.update_text()
        self.after(10, self.get_votes)

    def update_text(self):
        for name, data in self.labels.items():
            count, label = data
            label['text'] = "{} has {} votes".format(name, count)

    def get_votes(self):
        self.after(10, self.get_votes)

        self.readbuffer = self.readbuffer + self.s.recv(1024)
        temp = self.readbuffer.split('\n')
        self.readbuffer = temp.pop() #save the last (possibly incomplete) line for later
        if self.readbuffer == "":
            pass #no further messages in the queue
            #you should add a sleep time here for the sake of your hot NIC

        for line in temp:
            print(line)

            if "PING" in line:
                s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode())
                break

            user = getUser(line)
            message = getMessage(line)

            print "{} typed: {}".format(user, message)

            if "!commands" in message:
                sendMessage(self.s, " ".join(["!"+option for option in self.labels]))
                break

            for option in self.labels:
                if "!"+option in message:
                    self.labels[option][0] += 1
                    print self.labels[option][0]
                    self.update_text() 

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

What happens when I run the code, is that the chatbot works; if I type "!commands" or "!voteA" it will respond to that nicely, however, the GUI window isn't opening. I can see in my dock (I'm a mac user) that it's trying to open a window, but it freezes and then I have to force quit it. It's not giving an error in the compiler though. Does anyone have any idea what I've messed up?

Comment: This is not app ! Why use single class ! Leave this things. Signal wait what ? One freezing, the application go to garbage.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely understand, what do you mean with application go to garbage?